# Custom Model in Opencart giving error when I try to call function in it

Tags: php, opencart

I created a new model in OpenCart in a folder called catalog/model/donate/campaign.

```
<?php
class ModelDonateCampaign extends Model {
public function addCampaign($data) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `
        " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign`  
        SET campaign_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_name']) 
        . "', campaign_description = '" . $this->db->escape(['campaign_description']) 
        . "', campaign_startdate = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_startdate']) 
        . "', campaign_enddate = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_startdate'])
        . " '")


    return $order_id;
}



}
?>
```

In my controller I have...;

```
$this->language->load('donate/campaign');
$this->model_donate_campaign->addCampaign($data);
```

the error Im receiving is for when I try to call the last function...

Fatal error: Call to a member function addCampaign() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\charity\catalog\controller\donate\newcampaign.php on line 21

Is there part of the procedure that Im missing for setting up a model?

Thank you

Comment: what is C:\xampp\htdocs\charity\catalog\controller\donate\newcampaign.php on line 21

Comment: The problem is `$this->model_donate_campaign` isn't an object.  I don't know enough about OpenCart but do you have to instantiate the class into `$this->model_donate_campaign`?

Comment: thats the controller file and line 21 is this function... `$this->model_donate_campaign->addCampaign($data);`

Comment: Hi Devon, in OpenCart Im pretty sure you dont have to in this situation,  but I dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to first load model like

```
$this->load->model('donate/campaign');
```

then use

```
$this->model_donate_campaign->addCampaign($data);
```

and don't use `$this->language->load('donate/campaign');` if you have not created language file that is  `catalog/language/donate/campaign.php`

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I confused that one!